# Recut part of an image and gradually fade out the rest

Tags: photos

I want to highlight a certain part of an image by recutting it and fading away the rest gradually.
Moments later, I'd like to restore the whole picture back gradually.

[image]
I've been told this gif was done in the following web, but I cannot find the way to highlight a specific region

https://www.photo-kako.com/en/gif-animation/

A variation of this effect is the gradual superimposition of one picture over another, and then the gradual disappearance of the former.

I am sorry I do not know the technical name of these effects.
I am not knowledgeable so I do not know what software to use. If available online, I'd go that way.

Comment: Can you add an example showing what you mean visually?

Comment: @tomh I've added an example. I want to select which part of the image stays while the rest fades in and out

Comment: Do you want to make a GIF or a video?  Are you on a Mac or a PC? Do you have any video software already?